# Laravel 5.4 : Email cannot be sent from online server

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, smtp

I want to sent email to user when he first create an account. This works fine on localhost (I am using mailtrap.io for sending emails from localhost), but when I tried it on online server with my real email id, it does not work.

This is `.env` file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.easyname.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=no_reply@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

This is my `config/mail.php` file. I have set the Mail Encryption to SSL in both of my files.

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
    |            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.easyname.com'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'no_reply@mydomain.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'My name'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

This is my controller function:

```
$data = [
    'company_name' => $company_name,
    'login_email'  => $login_email,
    'password'     => $plain_password
];

Mail::send('emails.comp_ver_emails', $data, function($message) use ($data){
    $message->to($data['login_email']);
    $message->subject('Please verify your email address to get started');
});

return redirect()->back()->with('success','Thank you');
```

Comment: You use port 465 (SMTP Secure), but explicitly specify NULL as the encryption protocol.
Try using 25 or tls instead and if that still doesn't work please specify the actual error message.

Comment: 465 (for me is that with cpanel) if you don't set SSL it'll fail to send

Comment: I did set it to ssl in both .env and mail.php files but it still does not work.

Comment: I think change MAIL_PORT=465 to MAIL_PORT=2525